# How to dynamically wrap code inside a block in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, dynamic, block

Suppose a certain part of code needs to be run inside a different block/context, depending on a configuration option. For example,

```
if silence
  silence_stdout do
    # do something
  end
else
  # do the same thing
end
```

Is there a way to write this without repeating the `# do something` code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on how much code "do something" is you could throw it in a lambda:

```
something = -> { do_something }
if silence
  silence_stdout &something
else
  something.call
end
```

or throw it in a method:

```
def something
  # Do something, lots and lots of something.
end

if silence
    silence_stdout &method(:something)
else
    something
end
```

You could also turn the logic inside out a bit:

```
def no_op
  yield
end
def silence_stdout
  # Do whatever and then...
  yield
end

m = method(silence ? :no_op : :silence_stdout)
m.call do
  # Do something
end
```

Or you could use whole classes or just lambdas instead of methods in that last one.

Comment: Ah ah! #3 is exactly what I was looking for - I knew it had to be possible. Thanks.

Comment: @Hunter: Thanks, I ♥λ and I think they don't get nearly as much use as they should.

Comment: @muistooshort I was really disappointed the other day, another grad level student that I work with didn't know what a lambda expression was, hadn't even heard of one...

Comment: @Hunter: That's sad, you should print up some "Save the Lambdas" bumper stickers.